# UITextView setText is not updating the text

Tags: ios, ios4, interface-builder, uitextview

In my nib, I have a `UITextView` component.

In my code I have a `UITextView` field and I have used Interface Builder to make sure that the two are connected (at least I think I did that by dragging from "Files Owner" and dropping it on the `UITextView` in Interface Builder and selecting my member variable).

Now, when I update the text via `setText`, the UITextView still remains blank.

Thanks
DeShawn

Comment: Where are you calling `setText`?  It won't do anything until the nib is loaded because the outlet will be nil.  Call `NSLog(@"%@", yourMemberVariable);` immediately before the call to see if you're actually seeing the text view or not.

Comment: I am calling it after the nib is loaded... How do I make 100% sure this variable is actually bound to the interface element?

Comment: The logging I suggested would tell you exactly that.

Comment: You are rigjht.  It says null.  Why would it say that?

Answer (score 4):

Have you used

```
  @property(nonatomic,retain) UITextView *yourTextViewName;
```

then

```
  @synthesize yourTextViewName;
```

in `.m` file?

If yes, use the following code in `viewDidLoad` after updating the value to check:

```
   NSLog(@"Text View Value = %@",yourTextViewName.text);
```

Answer (score 3):

If it isn't figured it out yet;
check out [iOS Text View Not Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731874/ios-text-view-not-updating)

The referencing yourTextViewName must be an `IBOutlet UITextView *yourTextViewname`
Then add the `@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *yourTextViewName`.
Add the `@synthesize yourTextViewName` in the corresponding .m file.

To set the text, use

```
yourTextViewName.text = @"some text";
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound crazy, but I had to explicitly set the hidden property of UITextView to NO in code and then it started showing up. See if this works for you.

Comment: But the problem does not appear to be that the text view is hidden but that it is empty.